# Listening UDP messages in specific ports

Tags: java, udp

I am new to UDP programming using Java. I have written the following UDP server and client program just to try out the concepts. Below is the client program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

public class QuoteClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        try {
             socket = new DatagramSocket();
             byte[] buf = new byte[256];
             String messg = "Hello UDP Server\n";

             while (true) {
                 buf = messg.getBytes();
                 InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName ("127.0.0.1");
                 DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket (buf, buf.length, address, 4000);
                 socket.send(packet);

                 Thread.sleep(10000);
             }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            System.out.println("Timeout error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Client error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the server program:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class QuoteServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket packet = null;
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(4000);
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName ("127.0.0.1");
            while (true) {
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 5000);
                socket.receive(packet);
                String received = new String(packet.getData());
                System.out.println(received);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

My idea was to write a UDP client that will send packets to "localhost" at port 4000 and a server that will listen for packets at the same host adn port. But here my server listens to any address and any port. So how to specify the address and port in the server program? Also if a message is broke into several packets, is there a standard way to combine those packets together in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct - by calling DatagramSocket(4000) your server is listening only on port 4000 but on any address.  If you want a specific local address to listen on, use DatagramSocket(4000, local_address)

Also you don't need to specify an address and port on your receiver's DatagramPacket, i.e. the 5000 is not necessary.

I suggest you use tcpdump or Wireshark to see if your network traffic is getting through.

There's no standard way of combining UDP datagrams into larger messages.  You'll have to implement that yourself using a counter or other identifier. Also note that UDP is not guaranteed delivery, so you need to handle the case where you don't receive all pieces of a message.

Comment: So is it like the server will broadcast the packets to all ports and the client will request it from a speciific port? I am basically trying to listen to UDP messages (stock prices) from NASDAQ which they broadcast to a specific channel. So we will have to develop a client which will listen to the NASDAQ server and port, right? How will the messages be broadcasted to that particular port if se do not need to specify a port in server program?

Comment: In this case NASDAQ is "multicasting" on a multicast address to a given port. First, you need to subscribe to the multicast address, and then your client can listen for datagrams on the port they are sending to. Your routers in between must support multicast subscriptions, some firewalls might block them.  Take a look at:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html